# Take thousand value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have values like below I need to take only the thousand value in sql.

38,**635**.123
90,**232**.89
123,**456**.47888

I need to take result as below.
635
232
456

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT,YourColumn) % 1000
FROM dbo.YourTable
```

Answer (score 3):

Cast it as an `int` so that we not only drop the decimal places off, but also ensure integer division takes place:

```
SELECT CAST(YourColumn as int) % 1000
```

The `%` operator (modulo) essentially divides the left side by the right side and returns the remainder.  So, if we divide `123,456` by `1000`, using integer division, the result would be 123 with a remainder of 456.  Using the `%` operator, we just get the `456` part returned.

Answer (score 2):

Another method:

```
select right(cast(11.500 as int), 3) --> 11
select right(cast(38635.123 as int), 3) --> 635
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your value is numeric, you can use modulo arithmetic:

```
 select cast(col as int) % 1000
```

(You can also use `bigint` or a `decimal` value if an integer is not big enough to hold the value.)

If it is not numeric, then you can use string operations to get the three digits before the period or after the comma (assuming one or the other is always present).

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT RIGHT(ROUND(REPLACE(YourColumn ,',','') ,0,-1),3)
```